# What is the best way to integrate attachments in SharePoint?

Tags: database, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am working on a Contract / Invoicing project, I made the contract table and I need to add the contracts in PDF or Word form.
I wonder what is the best way to integrate attachments in sharepoint, do I have to use a library or is it better to work with an attachment column in the contract list

Answer (score 1):

Several benefits to each.

Use a library when:

- The focus is the document. The metadata/columns is secondary.
- Each document is unique, not part of a set.
- The content of the document needs to be indexed for search, and uniquely found. (The link in the search results points to the document.)

Use a list with attachments when:

- The focus is the metadata/columns and there may be zero or many related documents.
- You need a list item even if there is no document, or no document yet.
- It's OK when you search for a keyword found in one of the documents and you get the list item returned, not the document. (You would then need to open each attachment to find the search for term.) I.e. the link in the search results points to the list item, not the document.)

Use a Document Set when:

- You need a focus on a set of documents, kind of like a folder with metadata that contains zero to many files.
- You need to automatically create a collection of documents each time you create a new Document Set. (New hire form, parking permit, photo id appointment, training schedule, etc.)
- You like having a "home page" / information panel for each set of documents.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mike, i have another question please, i have two tables on sharepoint Thank you for your response Mike, i have another question please, i have two lists on sharepoint, Contract and project, the relation between this two tables is many many, my question is : how can i do this reltion with sharepoint 

Second question, i have a list prestation in relatioon with another list external, in another sharepoint, the relation is many many, how can i solve this problem please

Comment: SharePoint supports one to many using lookup columns. I don't think there is any kind of a many to many feature.